# UnicodeDecodeError('charmap') while inserting my data to MySql database

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, unicode

I am **scraping** some websites. I am getting some text and inserting them into my database. The text which I scrape could be in any language including English. I want to keep all the texts in my database with no loss. sometimes I get exceptions while inserting into the database. All of the exceptions are the same. an exception example is like this.

```
Arguments: (UnicodeDecodeError('charmap', b'Overview :\nGeneral\n1.\nEligibility\nThis \xe2\x80\x9cCall for Expression of Interest\xe2\x80\x9d is open for Individual Consultants.\n2. \nPurpose\nThe aim of the Call is to establish a qualified pool of consultants who can deliver professional services on a short-term basis for the conduct of various activities including but not limited to provision of consultancy services
```

I see it's because of some maybe undefined characters. how can I avoid them and make sure that I won't get any UnivodeDecodeError and my data will be inserted into my database.

here is what I have tried before.

```
final_text = scraped_text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')


op { final_text = final_text }
session.add (op)
session.commit()
session.flush()
```

here is my database table scheme
[image]

P.S it is really important to insert the data into the database and note the **scraped** text is not English all time. it could be french,Dutch,..... your help is much appreciated.

sample text which caused the exception

> Message: 'commit exception UNDP procurement'
> Arguments: (UnicodeDecodeError('charmap', b'Overview :\nRequest for Proposal (RFP) for a consultancy service to conduct a review of
> routine existing data collection tools and supplementary survey
> manuals from a gender perspective and publish a standard basic data
> collection tools and supplementary manuals for surveys and
> administrative data.\nThe United Nations Entity for Gender Equality
> and the Empowerment of Women (UN Women) plans to procure a consultancy
> service a consultancy service to conduct a review of routine existing
> data collection tools and supplementary survey manuals from a gender
> perspective and publish a standard basic data collection tools and
> supplementary manuals for surveys, and administrative dataas described
> in this Request for Proposal and its related annexes. UN Women now
> invites sealed proposals from qualified proposers for providing the
> requirements as defined in these documents.\nIn order to prepare a
> responsive proposal, you must carefully review, and understand the
> contents of the following documents:\nThis letter (and the included
> Proposal Instruction Sheet (PIS)\nInstructions to Proposers (Annex
> I)available from this
> link:[http://www.unwomen.org/-/media/headquarters/attachments/sections/about%20us/procurement/un-women-procurement-rfp-instructions-en.pdf?la=en&vs=3939\nTerms](http://www.unwomen.org/-/media/headquarters/attachments/sections/about%20us/procurement/un-women-procurement-rfp-instructions-en.pdf?la=en&vs=3939%5CnTerms)
> of Reference (TOR) (Annex 2)\nEvaluation Methodology and Criteria
> (Annex 3)\nFormat of Technical Proposal (Annex 4)\nFormat of Financial
> Proposal (Annex 5)\nProposal Submission Form (Annex 6)\nVoluntary
> Agreement to Promote Gender Equality and Women\xe2\x80\x99s
> Empowerment (Annex 7)\nUN Women Model Forms of Contract (Annex
> 8)\nGeneral Conditions of Contract (Annex 8)\nJoint
> Venture/Consortium/Association Information Form (Annex 9)\nSubmission
> Checklist (Annex 10)\nThe Proposal Instruction Sheet (PIS) -below-
> provides the requisite information (with cross reference numbers)
> which is further detailed in theInstructions to Proposers (Annex
> I)\nDetailed Instruction governing below listed summary of the
> \xe2\x80\x9cinstructions to proposers\xe2\x80\x9d are available in the
> Annex I (\xe2\x80\x9cInstruction to Proposers\xe2\x80\x9d) accessible
> from this link:\nDeadline for submission : Date and Time:Monday 06
> July 2020 5:00 PM(EAT)\nAddress of proposal submission : \xe2\x98\x92
> Electronic submission of Quotations:
> https://ungm.in-tend.co.uk/unwomen/aspx/Home \nPlease note that
> proposers should attach the below additional documents :\nCompany
> Registration Certificate \xe2\x80\x93 mandatory\nAudited Financial
> Statement\nTestimonial/Previous Track Record.\nContact address for
> requesting clarifications on the solicitation documents:
> \nhttps://ungm.in-tend.co.uk/unwomen/aspx/Home\n ', 1993, 1994,
> 'character maps to '),)
>
> ```
> Process finished with exit code -1
> ```

Comment: I don't know who downvote our question. and what could be his/her reason while this problem is a big headache to me now.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback, and the code that creates your sqlalchemy engine (I assume the `session` object is a sqlalchemy session?).

Comment: The traceback is the _minimal_ information required for us to work out where and why there error is happening.

Comment: Are you sure you have `utf8mb4` at field level? Just because the table has this encoding doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @bato3 how can I be sure of it?

Comment: @TalibDaryabi `CREATE TABLE users ( name varchar(100) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL, signature varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  password char(32) NOT NULL)  CHARSET=utf8;` In this case default (**password**) is `utf8`, **name** is `ascii`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
final_text = scraped_text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

not `encode`.  The theory here is that 8-bit strings are "encoded" and need to be "decoded" to convert to Unicode strings.  The string you posted decodes just fine.  Those special characters are "smart quotation marks".